# Why can't I debug my Android app on my phone?

Tags: android, visual-studio-debugging

I used to be able to select my phone from list of devices and debug on the phone. But now (for no obvious reason) my phone's OS is not on the debugging list. That list is all Pixel 5 and they use the emulator. (My phone is a Samsung). How to get VS to debug on my phone? It's plugged into my computer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ron, any update on this case?

Comment: No. Still cannot.

Comment: Now when I invoke one of my dialog boxes the app abends. Of course, since I can't debug, finding out why is very nontrivial.

Comment: When the phone is plugged in to the computer, the phone is charging via USB. Does this interfere with debugging? I get that "Waiting for Debugger" message when I try to debug.

Comment: this should not interfere debugging.

Comment: I think the issue was the option "Wait for Debugger" in Developer Options. Once I set this to off, it runs OK.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I add this to my answer's following troubleshooting steps. Could you please [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question, this will be beneficial to others who encounter this issue and search for the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

As for the most recent updates the oldest supported device must use Android 11.

Comment: The phone's Android version is 13. I turned dev options off and ten on etc. Not sure about how to change usb ports. 

This used to work as soon as my phone was plugged into my computer. But now, it's all Pixel 5 on the emulator.

Comment: By restarting Visual studio I got Samsung as a debugging choice. BUT now, all I get on the Android is a "Waiting for Debugger" message.

Comment: Visual Studio? I am using IntelliJ IDEA (father of Android Studio).

Ok, you may need to switch to the "Physical" tab to the device manager and look for the device. If the device is listed, it should show an indicator telling it is "on line". Else, it has no contact.

If running on Windows, probably VS can't see the connection. You should revoke the connection certificates and switch off and on the USB debug option. Also I found WiFi debugging working more reliably and cable free.

Comment: Six months ago I could plug my phone into the computer, make updates, build, archive and immediately debug on the phone. Never any problems. 6 months later, it's just awful. Now all I get is "Waiting for Debugger" whatever what means. Whatever the Android devs did, it is quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing again the phone developer options and usb debugging steps.
Try checking the usb port working correctly or not(try to change port to check).

Comment: I think your answer isn't very helpful.
It does not identify the problem and does not suggest a technical solution. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## Updates:

Thanks for Ron's sharing, I'm supplementing final solution of this question here in addition to the previous general troubleshooting steps:

So the solution to this case is turn off the "Wait for Debugger" option in the device developer options:

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#debugging

In case anyone encounters a similar issue in the future, you can take a look of the original answer, this original answer is still helpful in narrowing down the issue

## Original Answer:

Please check the following:

**1, Make sure you [Enable USB debugging on Samsung](https://help.airdroid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045374013-How-to-Enable-USB-debugging-on-Samsung-)**

This normally need to turn on Developer options via "tapping Build Number multi times", after that, turn on USB Debugging.

**2, Pay attention the connection mode is Charge Only or is transfer files when you connect the Samsung to PC.**

If it is Charge only, try to select transfer files. Otherwise the data may unable to transfer.

**3, Make sure there is available Driver of your Samsung device.**

You can install the Driver here:

[Samsung Android USB Driver](https://developer.samsung.com/android-usb-driver)

Without this, I think you will not be able to connect successfully.

**4, Use adb to check whether the device is connnected succesfully.**

From you description, to tell the truth, the information is not enough, so this situation may even not caused by VS. Have your device even be successfully connected to the PC? This is a question, if not, leave alone the Visual Studio. This is my notion.

[android developer platform tools](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools)

It is a zip file, after download it, extract to a path, then use command prompt and directly go to the adb route or configure the adb route to the global path.(I think you know what I mean so I will not share detailed steps of this.)

After that, use 'adb devices' to list the devices.

Commands are here:

[AdbCommands](https://gist.github.com/Pulimet/5013acf2cd5b28e55036c82c91bd56d8)

**5, Consider whether the issue comes from hardware/physical issue.**

1'' Whether the cable you use to connect is charge only cable or "charge only+transfer file" cable?

Some cable don't support transfer file, it can only charge, it is based on it's physical structure.

2'' Is the USB socket no problem?

You may have many USB sockets of your PC, try others.

**6, Reset the Visual Studio settings.**

If there is no Visual Studio settings that you want to keep and you want to jump out of the wired situation, you may use this:

[/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)

This will reset mostly VS settings, they will return to default.

**7, Restart the Visual Studio.**

Sometimes merely restart will solve the issue, you can also remove the .vs folder under the sln root directory(Move this will make the Visual Studio reconfigure and reload the entire solution.).

You can also try to create a new project to see whether the issue still exists.

Comment: ADB says the Android is connected. So why doesn't the debugger attach?

Comment: @Ron If so, the issue may comes from the visual studio configurations, have you tried reset the settings of VS(I have shared this in my answer.)?

Comment: @Ron What about the device in 'this PC'? Does the issue still exist, if still exist the issue may comes from the device itself. What about try in another PC, does the issue still appear in this situation? By the way, sometimes you need to press 'trust' when a window pop out in android device to ask whether you trust the PC.